# How to format the content of any .txt file in one line by removing \n with Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Just a quick question guys... I would like to recover the content of a formatted .txt file in one line. for instance consider the following content of a .txt file:

```
Me encanta todos los electrodomésticos LG, ya que últimamente se han actualizado en un 200% en tecnología de punta respecto de las demás marcas que lo aventajaban antiguamente, sus repuestos son fáciles de encontrar en caso de defectos y mas económicos de otros, es una excelente secadora, gran capacidad de ropa y lo mas importante es que reúne las dos grandes funciones, lavar y secar en un sólo producto y cualquier persona la puede hacer funcionar, ya que su panel es muy sencillo y además no es ruidosa, se las recomiendo a todos.
Además, posee una gran característica que es, que si es que no quisieras utilizar todas las funciones, puedes seleccionar sólo las que desees, por ejemplo si es quires sólo lavar, se programa para esa función en específico y si es deseas todo el proceso menos secar, por ejemplo, de igual forma se selecciona las funciones requeridas.
```

I would like to recover it in one line like this:

```
Me encanta todos los electrodomésticos LG, ya que últimamente se han actualizado en un 200% en tecnología de punta respecto de las demás marcas que lo aventajaban antiguamente, sus repuestos son fáciles de encontrar en caso de defectos y mas económicos de otros, es una excelente secadora, gran capacidad de ropa y lo mas importante es que reúne las dos grandes funciones, lavar y secar en un sólo producto y cualquier persona la puede hacer funcionar, ya que su panel es muy sencillo y además no es ruidosa, se las recomiendo a todos. Además, posee una gran característica que es, que si es que no quisieras utilizar todas las funciones, puedes seleccionar sólo las que desees, por ejemplo si es quires sólo lavar, se programa para esa función en específico y si es deseas todo el proceso menos secar, por ejemplo, de igual forma se selecciona las funciones requeridas.
```

So far I tried this:

```
with open('/path/test_text.txt', 'r') as content_file:
    content1 = content_file.read().splitlines()

    print content1
```

Then, this is the output:

```
['Me encanta todos los electrodom\xc3\xa9sticos LG, ya que \xc3\xbaltimamente se han actualizado en un 200% en tecnolog\xc3\xada de punta respecto de las dem\xc3\xa1s marcas que lo aventajaban antiguamente, sus repuestos son f\xc3\xa1ciles de encontrar en caso de defectos y mas econ\xc3\xb3micos de otros, es una excelente secadora, gran capacidad de ropa y lo mas importante es que re\xc3\xbane las dos grandes funciones, lavar y secar en un s\xc3\xb3lo producto y cualquier persona la puede hacer funcionar, ya que su panel es muy sencillo y adem\xc3\xa1s no es ruidosa, se las recomiendo a todos.', 'Adem\xc3\xa1s, posee una gran caracter\xc3\xadstica que es, que si es que no quisieras utilizar todas las funciones, puedes seleccionar s\xc3\xb3lo las que desees, por ejemplo si es quires s\xc3\xb3lo lavar, se programa para esa funci\xc3\xb3n en espec\xc3\xadfico y si es deseas todo el proceso menos secar, por ejemplo, de igual forma se selecciona las funciones requeridas.']
```

The issue with the above code is that I get a comma separation from the newline: `se las recomiendo a todos.', 'Adem\xc3\xa1s,`. Is there any way to remove this type of special characters from the output?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: `text.replace('\n', ' ')`

Comment: Um.... how about smaller lines in your example. I feel like I'm being punked.

Comment: You split the lines into a list. When you print the list python adds quotation marks around the strings and commas between the items of the list. Its simlar to when you write a list in your program such as `my_list = ['foo', 'bar']`. Those quotes and commas aren't in the list you wrote - they are there to tell the python parser that you want a list.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @tdelaney. I know that the `'` are different from `,`. I was refering to the `\n` which is the second element of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `join`.

```
with open('/path/to/file') as f:
    string = f.read().splitlines()
    oneline = ''.join(string)
    # do something with oneline
```

What you have is a list of values, where each value is a line. By joining them with no separator, you can get your one-line file.